# Implementar um contador de piscada na detecção de face haar cascade

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, opencv, numpy

Como q faço para exibir a quantidade de piscadas das pessoas detectadas no momento.
O código abaixo detecta face com haar cascade, onde exibe um contador de faces.

```
from  __future__ import print_function #importa a funcao da biblioteca future
import cv2 

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #webcam

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")

while (cap.isOpened()):
ret,frame = cap.read()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) #faz a conversao pra cinza por ser mais leve pro pc
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.3, minNeighbors=5, flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE,minSize=(50, 50), maxSize=None)

if len(faces) > 0:
    print("Pessoa detectada!")
    text = "{} face(s) Encontrada(s)".format(len(faces))
    cv2.putText(frame, text, (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
        0.5, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x - 10, y - 20), (x + w + 10, y + h + 10), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = frame[y-15:y + h+10, x-10:x + w+10]

    cv2.imshow("imagem", frame) #mostra a face detectada

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): # q definido para sair do projeto
    break #para o programa

cap.release() #mostra as coordenadas da deteccao
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: tu tem um dataset que possua as imagens piscando das pessoas? Tu teria que retreinar este algoritmo nestas imagens, assim tu conseguiria detectar as piscadas

Answer (score 3):

Uma forma de você resolver esse seu problema é procurando uma abordagem relacionada a **facial landmarks**. Você precisa acompanhar as marcações referentes aos olhos e calcular o fechamento dos olhos com base na distância das marcações.

Abaixo está uma representação 2D de marcações faciais (*facial landmarks*). Considerando elas em um plano cartesiano, podemos medir a distância do ponto 40 para o ponto 37 para conseguirmos a largura do olho da pessoa. Feito isso, calculamos também as distâncias dos pontos 38 e 39 em relação aos pontos 42 e 41, respectivamente, para conseguir a altura do olho da pessoa.

Dessa forma, podemos comparar quadro a quadro a altura e a largura dos olhos e identificar mudanças típicas de uma piscada nessa relação de grandeza.

[image: Facial landmark]

Existem bibliotecas prontas para você conseguir trabalhar com *facial landmarks* sem ter que reinventar a roda. O site [pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/04/24/eye-blink-detection-opencv-python-dlib/) explica tudo isso que eu falei e dá alguns exemplos de código. Ele pode ser um ponto de partida para você começar a trabalhar com uma solução com *facial landmarks*.